# How to make secure local SQL database for C# application

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, setup-project

I have a C# application with .NET 3.5 and SQL SERVER 2008 R2.
I want to make a setup project and i want to install each user db while installation.

I use local db when i import database as application file, the database is available and anyone who has access to the laptop os has access to the database. because the local db' s are not for the multiuser scenarios.

how to secure the database file' s from access or being modified? it contains sensitive data for application behave.

Comment: are you worried about the whole db or the contents that you put into db? depending on this multiple scenarios are possible.

Comment: the important matter is contents of DB. when it comes to comparison  whole db is Second

Comment: Cool. So what you can do is for example use t-sql crypto functions (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173744.aspx) or encrypt in code using symmetric (e.g. Aes) or asymmetric (e.g. PKCS7 envelope) methods.

Comment: how can i encrypt the whole data with a key ? Is it even possible? and access it by that key

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create in sql windows authentication to server authentication 
then you can add username and password then you can secure your database

Comment: if you want to create database at the time of installation then you need installer class then give you reference in setup file

Comment: the data base file will be packed and ready to use for each different clients. should i use SQL impact?